# Unable to parse option value xxx.srt as image size in ffmpeg

Tags: windows, parsing, ffmpeg

I had already set environment variable for the ffmpeg in my windows,want to embed the srt file into my mp4 file with ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i f:\sample\dance.mp4 -vf subtitles='f:\sample\dance.srt'  f:\sample\out.mp4
```

It encounter a strange error:

```
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[subtitles @ 0000000002c2fd00] Unable to parse option value "sampledance.srt" as
 image size
    Last message repeated 1 times
[subtitles @ 0000000002c2fd00] Error setting option original_size to value sampl
edance.srt.
[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 00000000005410c0] Error applying options to the filter.
[AVFilterGraph @ 0000000002940440] Error initializing filter 'subtitles' with ar
gs 'f:\sample\dance.srt'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
Conversion failed!
```

I copy the files `dance.mp4` and `dance.srt` into `f:\ffmpeg\bin`,then do the following:

```
cd  \d  f:\ffmpeg\bin
ffmpeg -i dance.mp4 -vf subtitles=dance.srt   out.mp4
```

It works fine, how can make ffmpeg parse the option value  `f:\sample\dance.srt` properly,make the command execute normally in my windows?

```
ffmpeg -i f:\sample\dance.mp4 -vf subtitles='f:\sample\dance.srt'  f:\sample\out.mp4
```

@kesh,it is no use to write as below:

```
ffmpeg -i f:\sample\dance.mp4 -vf "subtitles='f:\sample\dance.srt'"  f:\sample\out.mp4
```

Comment: Likely due to the cli escaping. If you put `subtitles='f:\sample\dance.srt'` inside of double quotes, the former should work, i.e., `"subtitles='f:\sample\dance.srt'"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parsing rules for FFmpeg filter graph are different from the rules used for other arguments.

Since `'e\sample\dance.srt'` is a value of a filter graph argument, we have to add an escape character before every special character:

```
ffmpeg -i e:\sample\dance.mp4 -vf subtitles='e\:\\sample\\dance.srt' e:\sample\out.mp4
```

The subject is described in [Notes on filtergraph escaping](http://underpop.online.fr/f/ffmpeg/help/notes-on-filtergraph-escaping.htm.gz) (among other places).