# Unable to parse option value xxx.srt as image size Error applying option 'original_size' to filter 'subtitles': Invalid argument

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, exec, fluent-ffmpeg

```
const strFile = `http://localhost:8080/public/srtFiles/nombreArchivo.srt`
    
const localSubtitleFilePath = path.join(__dirname, 'nombreArchivo.srt');

 axios.get(strFile, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
    .then(response => {
        fs.writeFileSync(localSubtitleFilePath, Buffer.from(response.data));

        const outputFilePath = path.join(__dirname, '../../../public/videosSubtitled', `${videoName}`);
        console.log('Subtitle File Path:', localSubtitleFilePath);
        console.log('Output File Path:', outputFilePath);

        exec(`ffmpeg -i ${tempFilePath} -vf subtitles=${localSubtitleFilePath} ${outputFilePath}`, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
                console.log(stdout);
                console.log(stderr);
                console.log("❌  Something went wrong!");
                res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: 'Error al crear el video subtitulado' });
            } else {
                fs.unlinkSync(tempFilePath);
                fs.unlinkSync(localSubtitleFilePath);
                console.log("Done!  ");
            }
        });
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log("Error downloading subtitle file:", error);
        res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: 'Error al descargar el archivo de subtítulos' });
    });
```

Hi, I'm trying to add subtitles to a video with ffmpeg in a NodeJS app, but I have this error:
[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 0000024140111580] Unable to parse option value xxx.srt as image size Error applying option 'original_size' to filter 'subtitles': Invalid argument

I have tried to send the srt file by a public url and by a local file, but I have also a mistake.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71597897/unable-to-parse-option-value-xxx-srt-as-image-size-in-ffmpeg